# Java-Jersey based RESTful webservice : What is the best way to handle path param for a file entity

Tags: java, web-services, rest, jersey

I am writing a Java based REST web service using jersey. The entity for which I am writing the web service is a media file. A client requesting for a media file need to send the path and filename as the path param. The media path allowed can be up to a depth of five directories. Now the challenge is to write a single method to handle all the path depth possibilities. Using the path param is the only allowed choice in terms of the business scenario. Here is the method contract, which handles a media file request:

```
public Response getMediaFile(@PathParam("path") String path,
                        @PathParam("filename") String filename);
```

Problem with this method is that, if the request is like /media/filedir1/filedir2/filename then filename will not be fetch properly.

The solution I have implemented is that, I have overloaded this method to handle all the directories depth but I am not really convinced that this is the best solution:

```
public Response getMediaFile(@PathParam("path1") String path1, 
                        @PathParam("path2") String path2, 
                        @PathParam("filename") String filename);

public Response getMediaFile(@PathParam("path1") String path1, 
                                @PathParam("path2") String path2, 
                                @PathParam("path3") String path3,
                                @PathParam("filename") String filename);
```

And so on.

Comment: Can the file only be located in the innermost folder `/media/filedir1/filedir2/filename` or at an arbitrary level like `/media/filedir1/filename` or `/media/filedir1/filedir2/filename`. Do you have a limited set of real names for each `filedir` parameter?

Comment: @Tom As I mentioned in the problem description, the media path allowed can be up to a depth of five directories. It is not fixed a file can present in dir/filename or dir1/dir2/filename and so on.

Comment: Can you explain more in detail why the first solution doesn't work?

Comment: @perissf i believe i have provided all the relevant details. The only solution i could figure out is to put multiple methods for different directory path depth. But I am looking for any better solution

Comment: Uh, do you really think that _then filename will not be fetch properly_ contains all the relevant details?

Comment: @perissf As I am using path param, so firstpath param is directory second is filename. All good when directory is one levet but if directory is two level such as dir1/dir2 then filename will not be fetched.

Comment: Nothing wrong with Jersey, but if the technology decision is up to you, then for your next REST project, have a look at Spray (http://spray.io). It's a nice alternative, and you will be able to reuse your existing Java libraries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use a regular expression in your `@PathParam` annotation to handle all the path filtering logic. For example, this will give you a filepath that is at most 5 directories down:

```
@Path("{path:(?:[^/]+/){0,4}[^/]+}")
```

Then you'd inject that value into a method as expected:

```
@Path("{path:(?:[^/]+/){0,4}[^/]+}")
/* Other attributes too... */
public Response getMediaFile(@PathParam("path") String path) {
    File file=new File(MEDIA_HOME_DIR, path);
    if(file.exists()) {
        // Process file
    }
    else {
        // No such file
    }
}
```

The regular expression will handle the "five directory" limit, and if the number changes from five in the future it'll be easy to fix. You could easily filter the filenames more carefully too, if you needed to match only `.jpg` files (for example).

With that solved, you'll just have to serve the media. :)

Answer (score 1):

The [JAX-RS Specification](http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/jcp/jaxrs-2_0-fr-eval-spec/jsr339-jaxrs-2.0-final-spec.pdf) tells us about URI Templates:

> Template parameters can optionally specify the regular expression used to match their values. The default value matches any text and terminates at the end of a path segment

If you want to match across "the end of a path segment", use a proper regular expression. This one works for you:

```
@Path("{path:.*}/{filename}")
```

Comment: How would this work a media file with the same name exists in more than one folder